# Why don't we have a page in the help center on $\LaTeX$ notation?

Tags: feature-request

Many new users don't know how to use $\LaTeX$. Generally, if they write a mathematically-heavy post that needs $\LaTeX$ but doesn't have it, another user will either edit the post, show them to a page in the help center detailing how to use it, or, hopefully, both.

The issue is, we don't have that page.

[There's one on Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation), as well as [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). Why don't we have one? It seems just as necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does seem like a good idea. I will see what I can do.

In the meantime, please use those references as well as these:

[How do I add mathematical notation using MathJax (World Building)](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/607/how-do-i-add-mathematical-notation-using-latex-mathjax)

[MathJax tutorial and quick reference (Math)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thanks. I saw that Worldbuilding post (and contributed quite a lot to starting it!). We don't need something that detailed, do we? The reason we set that up was because many people on Wolrdbuilding aren't too science/math oriented and are more likely to be unfamiliar with it.